# props.stories.map is not a function?

Tags: reactjs

Hi I'm trying to make a simple news app to learn react. Keep getting an error which I don't understand. Why app worked fine with a json placeholder api. However now it's displaying the error props.stories.map is not a function.

Here is my code.

```
import NewsList from './components/NewsList';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()

    this.state = {
      stories: [],
    }
  }

componentDidMount() {
  fetch(`https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=gb&apiKey=${API_KEY}`)
      .then(res => res.json() 
      .then(data => this.setState({stories: data}))
      )
}

  render(){
    const { stories } = this.state
    return (
      <div className="App">
       <NewsList stories={stories} />
      </div>
    );
    }

  }


import Story from './Story'

import styled from 'styled-components'

const NewsList = props => {
   return(
       <NewsListWrapper>
        {
            props.stories.map(story => (
                <Story story={story} />
            )
          )
        }
       </NewsListWrapper>
   )
}







import React from 'react';

import styled from 'styled-components';

export const Story = props => (
    <StoryWrapper>
        <h2>{props.story.title}</h2>
        <p>{props.story.author}</p>
        <p>{props.story.articles}</p>
    </StoryWrapper>
)
```

I have console.log the api response and the data was being received fine. It's simply when I use this other api response.
And I've hidden my api_key just for this post, so it's not issues with that.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: This error normally means that the data you are trying to iterate over is not an array. Are you sure it is an array?

Comment: Your code seems to be fine! Check whether your `data` is array or not! Cause it looks like probably its an `object` (as if you're saying that you are receiving data). So check for its property like `data.stories` or whatever comes from request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In New API documentation (https://newsapi.org/docs/endpoints/top-headlines) you can see that your request return object of form

```
{
  status: string
  totalResults: number
  articles: Array
}
```

So you need to set to stories not `data` but `data.articles`:

```
fetch(`https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=gb&apiKey=${API_KEY}`)
      .then(res => res.json() 
      .then(data => this.setState({stories: data.articles}))
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 import NewsList from './components/NewsList';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()

    this.state = {
      stories: [],
      storiesData:[]
    }
  }

componentDidMount() {
  fetch(`https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=gb&apiKey=${API_KEY}`)
      .then(res => res.json() 
      .then(data => this.setState({stories: data}))
      )
}

  render(){
    const { stories } = this.state
    return (
      <div className="App">
       <NewsList stories={stories} />
      </div>
    );
    }

  }


import Story from './Story'

import styled from 'styled-components'

const NewsList = props => {
   console.log(props.stories);
   this.setState({storiesData:props.stories});
   return(
       <NewsListWrapper>
        {
            this.state.storiesData.map(story => (
                <Story story={story} />
            )
          )
        }
       </NewsListWrapper>
   )
}







import React from 'react';

import styled from 'styled-components';

export const Story = props => (
    <StoryWrapper>
        <h2>{props.story.title}</h2>
        <p>{props.story.author}</p>
        <p>{props.story.articles}</p>
    </StoryWrapper>
)
```